# Keeping the ttf files on server for Arial etc requires license?

Tags: css, fonts, licensing, truetype

I require to simply keep the .ttf files on my server for Arial, Comic Sans etc. i shall **not** install them.

This is required for Imagick.

Will this also require buying the licenses for these fonts? Or this is not considered any violation or distribution of the font and can be done without the license?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: this question might help some newbie searching the net crazily to resolve a situation. So please do not. This will not hurt anyone

Answer (score 2):

From what I can read on http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/faq8.htm you can keep fonts from the mscorefonts distribution just fine. (Arial and Comic Sans are part of it)

Hope it helps

Comment: The URL you mentioned no where mentions the need of getting the license in case of embedding fonts using \@font-face too. However, on SOF i have had people claim that one requires the license while using the \@font-face. Is this link credible then? Also then why does http://www.ascendercorp.com/ provide licensing?

Comment: From what I can read in EULA, they're not redistributable for profit. "Copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT may not be distributed for profit either on a standalone basis or included as part of your own product."

Comment: I cant accept your answer as I am still do not have a concrete answer. But I am upvoting the saME

Comment: The document cited is a copy of an old Microsoft page (possibly violating copyright). Microsoft’s current real core fonts FAQ: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/faq/faq8.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fonts only as permitted by the [rules set by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/faq/faq8.htm). They allow redistribution only “in their original form (.exe or .sit.hqx) and with their original file name”, so this excludes `@font-face` use.

If in doubt, contact Microsoft.